# Dynamo DB iOS dynamoDBObjectMapper store double

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-dynamodb

What is the proper way of managing a value of type double in dynamo db? I can successfully add a double to the database with `[dynamoDBObjectMapper save:]` but when I try to get it with `[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[DynamoTransaction class] expression:queryExpression]` it gives me following exception:

```
NSInvalidArgumentExeption
setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: amount)
```

my code for getting the object from the database is as follows:

```
-(void)loadTransactionsFromDatabase:(NSString*)userID successBlock:(void(^)(NSArray*))successBlock{
[self connectToInternetWithsuccessBlock:^{

    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = userID;
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = @YES;

    [[[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[DynamoTransaction class] expression:queryExpression]continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask*task){

        NSMutableArray*transactionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput*paginatedOutput = task.result;
        for(DynamoTransaction*databaseTransaction in paginatedOutput.items){
            Transaction*transaction = [[Transaction alloc]initWithDynamoTransaction:databaseTransaction];
            [transactionsArray addObject:transaction];
        }

        if(successBlock!=nil){successBlock(transactionsArray);}
        NSLog(@"loaded all my transactions from database");
        return nil;

    }]continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask*task){
        NSLog(@"Failed");
        return nil;
    }];
} andFailBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"loadTransactions Problem");
}];
}
```

It always works when I have a non decimal number in the database

What should I do?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved updating my pod (AWSiOSSDKv2 2.0.17 (was 2.0.13)).

see: [AWS IOS SDK DynamoDB Scan - MainThread works in emulador, but don't in device debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951973/aws-ios-sdk-dynamodb-scan-mainthread-works-in-emulador-but-dont-in-device-de/29115231#29115231)