# AWS IOS SDK DynamoDB Scan - MainThread works in emulador, but don't in device debugger

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my app I use DynamoDB scan that works fine in all emulador iOS versions in xCode, however, when I debug in device (iPhone 5c), the main thread don't works.

```
[[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[DDBTableRow class]
                  expression:scanExpression]
      continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
//Main Thread execution          
.
.
.
return nil;
  }] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
      if (task.error) {
          NSLog(@"refreshList Error");
      }
      return nil;
  }];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To start the tracker I added a exception breakpoint. This caused the code to stop at the point where the error occurs. fyi; Goto xcode->View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigator. In the left pane click on "+" and select "Add exception breakpoint". Run the application.

The exception occured in AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper - removeAttributes method. When this method tried to set object into mutableItem a messsage "*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil " was launched, exactly when tried to handle a double(number) item in the return object.
Oddly only in my device, not in all emulators in Xcode... So I updated my pod (AWSiOSSDKv2 2.0.17 (was 2.0.13)) and this problem was magically solved...